# Page turning animation in ios pdfkit singlepage displaymode

Tags: ios, animation, pdfkit, uiswipegesturerecognizer, singlepage

I've recently implemented a pdfviewer using the ios PDFKit library, and am using singlepage mode rather than continuous mode. Following the solution to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114530/5983905) I've implemented the page turning with a swipe handler however this just loads the next/prev page.

Is it possible to animate moving between the pages in singlePage mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enabling usePageController enabled UI page view controller scroll style scrolling

```
pdfView!.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
```

from here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfview/2877501-usepageviewcontroller

Comment: its works ? what I need to add in withViewOptions to get different animation ?