# iOS 13.1 PDFKit PDFView.go(to page:) isn't working

Tags: ios, swift

The Apple API isn't working on iOS 13.1, does anyone have the same issue or I did wrong way to use it.

I tried to get a PDFPage from PDFDocument.page(at: validPageIndex), the outcome page is with right index, and I set this page to PDFView.go(to: page) and the navigation isn't working.

```
let validPageIndex: Int = 11
guard let targetPage = document.page(at: validPageIndex) else { return }
print(targetPage.index)
// Print 11
pdfView.go(to: targetPage)
```

the line `pdfView.go(to: targetPage)` was executed but the page in PDF file stay at first page

Thanks for Usama Azam, my PDFView display direction is horizontal, seems it works on vertical.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this sample piece of code and it works for me to move page next and previous. You can follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50488223/10493570) to add a PDF view in Storyboard.

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!
var currentPage = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "pdf") {
        if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
            pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
            pdfView.autoScales = true
            pdfView.displayDirection = .vertical
            pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func previousPage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let validPageIndex: Int = currentPage - 1
    guard let targetPage = pdfView.document!.page(at: validPageIndex) else { return }
    print(targetPage.index)
    currentPage = currentPage - 1
    pdfView.go(to: targetPage)
}

@IBAction func nextPage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let validPageIndex: Int = currentPage + 1
    guard let targetPage = pdfView.document!.page(at: validPageIndex) else { return }
    print(targetPage.index)
    currentPage = currentPage + 1
    pdfView.go(to: targetPage)
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Usama, seems on vertical display direction it works, I tried my code with vertical display direction and the navigation works. Does it works for you on horizontal display direction?

Comment: @KeN please add this line
pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)

Comment: Hmm... but the request needs it to be continuous display mode

Comment: There's another better idea of swipe gesture if you like it https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114530

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it solves the problem in the SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable.

```
        if let doc = pdfView.document,
           let page = doc.page(at: pageNumber)
        {
            Task { @MainActor in
                pdfView.go(to: page )
            }
        }
```